# Annotate Web pages using given Ontology

Tags: semantic-web, jena, ontology, owl

i have to annotate some web pages using particular ontology of a particular domain and generate annotated web pages in RDF format.
so there is any open source tool available which will complete my requirement. i am new in jena programming. so please suggest some links or books.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can annotate your HTML page using [RDFa](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RDFa) markup (look at the example in the page) and then 
use [this library](https://github.com/shellac/java-rdfa) to convert the pages into RDF.

Answer (score 0):

If annotating means some semantic disambiguation, you need to do that manually like @loopasam propoesed. For clear mapping (e.g. `<title>` tag to `dc:title`) you might want to use XSLT to add the RDFa tags.